# The images are breaking on web pages hosted on nginx server

Tags: javascript, json, nginx, webserver, centos6

I have configured NGINX server on Centos 6.4  everything is working fine with my NGINX server but when i updated the another build in root directory then first time the web pages load successfully but when i refreshed the pages then my images and text from web pages are breaking. In root directory I have multiple builds.

```
/usr/share/nginx/html/build1
```

My nginx configuration is as fallows

```
user              nginx;
worker_processes  2;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

   access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;


    sendfile       on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;
    #keepalive_timeout  65;

    proxy_buffers 30 32k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;

    # Load config files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory
    # The default server is in conf.d/default.conf
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

   gzip  on;
   gzip_comp_level 6;
   gzip_vary on;
   gzip_min_length  1024;
   gzip_proxied any;
   gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript te$
   gzip_buffers 16 8k;

}
```

and

```
default.conf file 

server {

    listen       8080 default_server;
    server_name  _;
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
   #  location ~* .(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
    #   expires 365d;
   # }


    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    error_page  404              /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
```

Please suggest where i am going wrong

Comment: Have you checked for permissions of build1.2 directory?

Comment: Yes arshan  all directory are created by root with drwxr-xr-x   permission

Comment: What's the error message from `logs/error.log`?

Comment: When loading the website lot of jason files loading in that time one of the css files skiped and the website showing old images or break images such as  `images`  would be shown as   `__images__`  kind of things hapening